# Failure to load server rules using Sonar Scanner

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

I have an instance of SonarQube installed on a server of mine, and I am trying to run scans on Atlassian's Bamboo using the Sonar Scanner. When I attempt to run a scan the following error is thrown.

I am using the following version:
Bamboo: v6.6.1
SonarQube: v6.5
SonarScanner: 3.0.3.778

An extra bit of detail is that this error did not start happening for all builds at a specific time. One day this error was only showing up every 3-4 builds, and you could rebuild the same code and it didn't show up. But over a period of two weeks it appeared more and more until now where it will not go away.

---

```
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.533 INFO: Load server rules
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.587 DEBUG: GET 200 http://<url>/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=53ms
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.597 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.597 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.597 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.597 INFO: Total time: 2.399s
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.644 INFO: Final Memory: 46M/211M
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.644 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.647 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
build   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.647 DEBUG: Execution stop
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    12:32:16.644 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:283)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:177)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:256)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:245)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:119)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ModuleIssues
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        ... 28 more
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Rules
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        ... 42 more
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Rules
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        ... 56 more
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get rules
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultRulesLoader.loadFromStream(DefaultRulesLoader.java:51)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultRulesLoader.load(DefaultRulesLoader.java:43)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.RulesProvider.load(RulesProvider.java:47)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.RulesProvider.provide(RulesProvider.java:40)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        ... 61 more
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16    Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:158)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse$Rule.<init>(Rules.java:214)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse$Rule.<init>(Rules.java:184)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse$Rule$1.parsePartialFrom(Rules.java:1036)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse$Rule$1.parsePartialFrom(Rules.java:1030)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:495)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse.<init>(Rules.java:90)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse.<init>(Rules.java:46)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(Rules.java:1609)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(Rules.java:1603)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:192)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:210)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:215)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonarqube.ws.Rules$ListResponse.parseFrom(Rules.java:1154)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultRulesLoader.loadFromStream(DefaultRulesLoader.java:49)
error   04-Sep-2018 12:32:16        ... 79 more
```

Comment: Do you use custom rules? Have you changed any specific code (block) between those SonarQube runs?

Comment: Version of SonarQube you are using is quite old, can you upgrade to at least 6.7?